# How to instantiate QueueClient Object in ASP.Net Framework project?

Tags: asp.net, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am currently implementing logging using Azure Service Bus Queues for one of my .Net Framework project. However even after installing the WindowsAzure.ServiceBus, I was still unable to import the package into the file and use. Using the package manager console and running the command I am unable to find the package installed but indeed the package has been successfully installed when I open the 'manage nuget packages' dialog window.

I am looking for help if you have encountered similar issues before and how to go about solving it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a legacy package. The current package is [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.azure.servicebus). Use that one instead.

As for the package, both the legacy and the current packages are on the public NuGet feed. Looks like Visual Studio issue. Try the UI option (NuGet package manager) or a different tool for the validation.